# Notepad++ highlight transparency

Tags: notepad++, highlighting

I use dark themes and when I select a word, Notepad++ highlights all the occurences of that word in the current document. But the highlight color for matches other than the current word is somehow blended with the background and the highlighted text is not as clearly visible as it could be. The same thing happens when using "Find all" option in the Find dialog to mark the occurences. Is there a way to change this behavior such that the matched text has the same (full) opacity as the selected text?

[image: Highlight transparency]

Comment: i can confirm your issue ... there is no direct way to control that highlight background color in NP++ (v6.5.2)  ... all answers suggesting to edit "Smart Highlighting" do not work.

Comment: Which style are you using in that screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to *Settings*
2. Click `Style Configurator`
3. Under *Language*, select the appropriate language or Global Styles for all languages.
4. Under *Style*, select `Smart Highlighting`.
5. On Colour Style change the `Background colour` as you wish.

Comment: That's what I did. The problem is that the color doesn't have full opacity, but is blended with the background and is darker. However, if I do the same for "Selected text color" instead of "Background color", it is fully opaque. I cannot include example image due to low reputation.

Comment: Point us to a link in dropbox and we can attach the image for you.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/blr845dvl/ Notice the highlight color of `my` on 2nd line vs the others.

Comment: The only way I see for doing what you want is to select a even brighter collor for the `Smart Highlighting` parameter. That is because the Smart Highlighting parameter will always blend with `Selected text colour` on the selected line and Smart Highlighting will always merge with background on the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

Set all language specific backgrounds to black then set `current line` to the darkest blue and `Smart Highlighting` to the darkest gray.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can find is for you to use a background color 
for selected text that is a BG-color which you are not using 
as a foreground color for any of your text.

Your question has inspired me to eliminate this problem 
that I myself have always struggled with 
by using 'red' for the BG-color for selected text
since I have always made it a point to never use red 
for the foreground color of any text.

I now have my Background for 'Selected text colour' set to 
Red: 184
Green: 0
Blue:  0

I like it. Thanks for asking.